# Recover data from a failing hard drive

Tags: hard-drive, data-recovery

I have a failing external hard drive (WD Passport).  It has an ExFAT formatted partition from which I would like to recover as much data as possible.  There are one or two thousand files with sizes around 20-40 MB ([raw image files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raw_image_format)).

I made an Ubuntu 16.04 live USB.  What tools does it have available that can help me recover data from the drive?

---

Ubuntu has already been helpful because a simple `cp` command does not hang on files which it cannot read.  After a few seconds of trying it simply says "Input/output error" and moves on to the next file.  In comparison, OS X would not mount the volume at all and Windows 10 would get stuck indefinitely on files that couldn't be read.  With Ubuntu I got maybe 2/3 of the files using a single run of `cp`.

Is there anything I can do using Ubuntu beyond having run `cp` once on the directory I am interested in?  Are there tools that can attempt a more aggressive recovery (and would skip the files which were already copied)?  Note: I only have a live USB stick (2 GB). At this moment I don't have access to a computer with Linux installed permanently.

Note: I cannot `cd` into all directories on the broken volume, but the directories containing the files of interest seem to be fine. I am not looking for tools which are designed to look for files that seem to be lost from the file system.

Comment: I find it difficult to google for a solution.  I found several tools to fix an unbootable system or to recover deleted files from working hard drives. But I need something to deal with *a broken hard drive* that has not failed completely yet.  The ExFAT filesystem is a further difficulty.

Comment: Have a read of [Data Recovery](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery), I've used [Photorec](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery#Photorec) with some success in the past on SD cards...

Comment: @AJefferiss Thanks!  Is it correct that photorec ignore the file system structure and just extracts anything that looks like an image file?  That may not be the best route as I also have more than 1000 GB of images on the same drive which I don't need (already backed up).  It is "only" about 50 GB which are in danger of getting lost.

Comment: Looking at [PhotoRec Step By Step](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec_Step_By_Step) it'll just return everything it finds on the device, so not very suitable for what you need @Szabolcs

Comment: Oh dear, please guys stop recommending carving tools when the file system is clearly accessible!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use  `rsync`.  Something like this should work:

`rsync -av --ignore-errors /defective/disk /safe/disk`

It will copy all files that can be copied.  Errors will be ignored, and the copy continues.  If you omit that, the copy will stop upon an error.

Do note you might be interested in making a block by block copy of your disk.  This will create a huge file.  You can do this with `dd`.

`dd if=/dev/defectiveDisk of=/target/disk/block-by-block.imh bs=1G conv=notrunc,noerror`

This gives you an image of all recoverable blocks

This image, you can later mount as a loopback device.  That way you can concentrate on saving your files without straining the defective disk.

Comment: I was going to try `rsync` later today, but I was not sure that it can do anything that `cp` cannot (for this use case).  Is it better than `cp` for recovery?  `rsync` can ignore the files which were already copies before, right?  This way it can retry the bad ones multiple times.

Comment: Not exactly sure whether `cp` can ignore errors.  There is the `-f` option, but with a description like `if  an  existing  destination file cannot be opened, remove it and try again` I'm  a bit concerned what "remove" means in this context.
`rsync` is a good tool for these scenarios.  One of the advantages is that you can stop it, and continue where you left off.

Comment: Yes, `cp` ignores errors well, at least on Linux.  I used `cp -rnv` yesterday.  On OS X `cp` didn't work so well, then OS X refused to mount the volume afterwards ...  Should have went to Linux straight away.

Comment: Actually, you really should have made a disk image and stop working on the disk as soon as possible.

Comment: You should use `ddrescue` on a failing drive, not `dd`. The `noerror` option might skip a lot of good bytes depending on the block size.

Comment: That's why you specify the "conv=noerror".  It won't stop on error then.

Comment: If the `bs` is 1G, `conv=noerror` will skip 1 GB worth of data even if there is a single failing sector. This is basic knowledge written in any digital forensics textbook. This is absolutely not what you want and the suggestion of using `dd` is inadequate to say the least.

Answer (score 1):

Well I recommend a few softwares you can depend on while you have failing HDD to clone. They are dd_rescue, dd_rhelp and GNU ddrescue.  Out of these good tools , I prefer GNU ddrescue to go a head with. You can google how to work on these softwares. The above said softwares are all the different variants of famous dd application. GNU ddrescue is the successor of dd_resuce. Meanwhile all these packages are known in different package name in ubuntu and the info can be viewed over [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/211578/whats-the-difference-between-ddrescue-gddrescue-and-dd-rescue#211579)