# a busy box error arises of code V1.22.1

Tags: grub2, bootloader

Each time I logged in to the system, intrafms screen arises asking to face mannualy.
.if this problem has any permanent solution, kindly help me out of it..

[image]

When I run fsck mannually and entering into reboot ,the following screen arises.!!

---

This picture shows the error message.

[image]

It doesn't allow to install any app,update,upgrade .....Even no files are transfer between usb flash drive and laptop. Even the driveer is not showing in laptop.

The outputs of commands sudo /etc/fstab and sudo blkid[image]
Output of commands dmesg-[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [fsck error on boot: /dev/sda6: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY](https://askubuntu.com/questions/697190/fsck-error-on-boot-dev-sda6-unexpected-inconsistency-run-fsck-manually)

Comment: @Sanjaysahoo Did you mean to include two links to screenshots? Only one appears.

Comment: please check your kernel log (type "dmesg"). It looks like you have broken hardware.

Comment: It sounds like you were able to successfully run the manual `fsck`. Now the disk is mounting as **read-only**, which usually means there are more problems. Did you modify `/etc/fstab`? Edit your question to include the `terminal` output of `sudo cat /etc/fstab` and `sudo blkid`. Then send me a comment that starts with `@heynnema`.

Comment: **DO NOT** add new information as answers.  Instead, **edit your question** to add the information.

Comment: @heynnema-thanks.attached the outputs of the commands sudo cat /etc/fstab and sudo blkid

Comment: @sebastian stark-attaching the output of dmesg

Comment: @Sanjaysahoo please see my answer. Report back.

Answer (score 1):

The dmesg output you posted strongly suggests that your hard drive is broken. If you are very lucky, it's just a loose cable, but I doubt so. You should consider replacing your hard drive with a new one. If you do not have a backup, here is an example of what you can do to try to recover some data:

[Recover data from a failing hard drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/819206/recover-data-from-a-failing-hard-drive#819216)

To explain a bit the output you are seeing here: If your system is still able to boot, but detects errors on your hard drive, it will eventually drop you into a busybox recovery shell. As you noticed you can run various system commands here and sometimes recover from errors. The "V1.22.1" is not an error code but just the version number of the busybox program. "initramfs" is the part of the operating system that contains the busybox recovery shell.

The real error you are facing here is printed a bit before: fsck detected  unexpected inconsistencies and failed to fix them. This, in many cases, means that your hard disk is not working correctly anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Possible answer...

It looks like the hard drive is having trouble reassigning a potentially bad block #5546376. This may be a hardware error with the hard drive. Boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB and backup your important files now.

There's a slight possibility that this a NCQ problem with the hard disk. To try to fix this, do the following...

Either:

**Boot into recovery mode...**

- boot to the GRUB menu
- choose Advanced Options
- choose Recovery mode
- choose Root access
- at the # prompt, type `sudo mount -o remount,rw /`
- at the # prompt, type `sudo pico /etc/default/grub`
- locate the line that contains "quiet splash" and change it to look like:

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash libata.force=noncq"`

- <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> # to save the edit
- <kbd>Return</kbd> # to confirm the filename to save
- <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> # to exit the editor

`sudo update-grub` # update GRUB with the new info

`reboot` # reboot the computer

**Via the GRUB edit...**

- boot to the GRUB menu
- hit the <kbd>e</kbd> key to enter edit mode
- use the arrow keys to move the cursor
- find the "quiet splash" line and edit as above
- <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> # to continue with booting

note: this is only a temporary fix for the current boot