# Windows' partitions become read-only

Tags: dual-boot, read-only

In between when I am working, the windows partitions suddenly become read-only. When I restart the computer, I have to run fsck -y command to boot the system. The disk assessment is "72 bad sectors, Disk is ok."

The read-only problem used to be quite rare at first (once a month) and now it happens every time while I am working.
I have been unable to access settings irrespective of the partitions becoming read-only.

Note: I have windows installed alongside ubuntu.

Comment: Uh oh. Sounds like the disk may be having issues. What does [the SMART data on the drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/528072/how-can-i-check-the-smart-status-of-a-ssd-or-hdd-on-current-versions-of-ubuntu-1) say? Also, _please_ make sure you have a backup of all your important data _on a different drive_, and ideally off-site. It may also be time to replace the disk, depending on what the SMART info says

Comment: Backup your data as soon as possible. [Here](https://askubuntu.com/a/211579/1194692) is a link to take a look. This issue happen to me on a 500G HDD. I removed it and installed a new one. Fortunately the old disk still readable as external ntfs.